# How to make a function that displays different images based on viewport width?

Tags: javascript, html

I have this function that when clicking an image displays a preview.

```
function Show(id)
          {
              var PopUp=document.getElementById(id);
              PopUp.classList.toggle('active');
          }
```

I want to display another preview when the mobile version is displayed, aka when viewport-width is less than 1024.
I tried changing the function into this:

```
function Show(id1,id2)
          {
            const vw = Math.max(document.documentElement.clientWidth || 0, window.innerWidth || 0);
            if(vw >= 1025)
            {
              var PopUp=document.getElementById(id1);
              PopUp.classList.toggle('active');
            }

            else
              if(vw <= 1024)
              {
                var PopUp=document.getElementById(id2);
                PopUp.classList.toggle('active');
              }
          }
```

,but without success since on mobile version the function throws this error: "(index):93 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'classList' of null
at Show ((index):93)
at HTMLImageElement.onclick ((index):16)".

Any suggestions on how to solve this issue or how to make it work?

Comment: Why not use CSS media queries? That way you don’t need any scripts at all.

Comment: Update, I forgot to change from show(id1) to show(id1,id2) in html. :)))
Problem solved, works just right.